# How to create a Javascript array or object from an XML file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, data-structures, domparser

I must first state that I am not a champion in programming, although created a handy website using html, php, MySQL and some javascript. Clearly, JS is by far the language I am almost using as a baby !

I have a set of data in a xml file with the following structure (sorry for the bad characters encoding) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
<markers> 
 <marker lat="50.84310" lng="4.39330" name="7.7cm Sockel Flak 16 RheinMetall" category="FlakKanonen" nation="Allemagne" typecanon="Artillerie de DCA" lieu="Bruxelles - MusÃ©e Royal de l'ArmÃ©e" pays="Belgique" url="../AfficheCanonGET.php?IdCanonAffiche=170" /> 
 <marker lat="43.13810" lng="-80.26170" name="15cm sFH 13 L/14" category="SchwerenKanonen" nation="Allemagne" typecanon="Artillerie lourde" lieu="Brantford (ON) - Monument" pays="Canada" url="../AfficheCanonGET.php?IdCanonAffiche=256" />  
 <marker lat="61.00500" lng="24.45780" name="10cm K 14" category="LeichtKanonen" nation="Allemagne" typecanon="Artillerie lÃ©gÃ¨re" lieu="Hameenlinna - Finnish Artillery Museum" pays="Finlande" url="../AfficheCanonGET.php?IdCanonAffiche=317" />  
 <marker lat="45.88740" lng="11.04740" name="7cm M 99 GebK" category="GebirgsKanonen" nation="Autriche-Hongrie" typecanon="Artillerie de montagne" lieu="Rovereto - Museo Storico Italiano della Guerra" pays="Italie" url="../AfficheCanonGET.php?IdCanonAffiche=733" /><marker lat="-35.21550" lng="149.14510" name="13cm K 09 L/35" category="SchwerenKanonen" nation="Allemagne" typecanon="Artillerie lourde" lieu=" Mitchell, ACT - AWM reserve" pays="Australie" url="../AfficheCanonGET.php?IdCanonAffiche=1519" /> 
</markers>
```

This xml file is used in a javascript code for placing markers on a GoogleMap. Well it used to since the code does not work anymore since GoogleMap migrated to APIV3, without portability of the xml importing function I was using.

I managed to rewrite the map code in the new API v3 language, but I am stuck in what is probably very simple for you : Despite reading tens of similar threads, I am unable to adapt a code in javascript to transfer these xml file data in a javascript array

Here is what I am hoping to create :

```
marqueurCanonTest4[0] = {
  latitudeCanon: "-34.94570",
  longitudeCanon: "138.58050",
  nomCanon: "7.7cm FK 16",
  categorieCanon: "LeichtKanonen",
  nationCanon: "Allemagne",
  typeCanon: "Artillerie lÃ©gÃ¨re",
  lieuCanon: "Adelaide, SA  - Keswick Barracks, Army Museum of South Australia",
  paysCanon: "Australie",
  url: "../AfficheCanonGET.php?IdCanonAffiche=1"
};
marqueurCanonTest4[1] = {
  latitudeCanon: "-36.14640",
  longitudeCanon: "146.91680",
  nomCanon: "7.7cm FK 16",
  categorieCanon: "LeichtKanonen",
  nationCanon: "Turquie",
  typeCanon: "Artillerie lÃ©gÃ¨re",
  lieuCanon: "Bandiana, VIC - Army Museum",
  paysCanon: "Australie",
  url: "../AfficheCanonGET.php?IdCanonAffiche=2"
};
```

etc ...

I have tried to use `XMLHttpRequest`, but probably incorrectly.

What are ways of achieving my goal?

Comment: Regarding all the provided answers, are there any questions left?

Comment: Yes, I am still needing some help since the 'fetch' call created array does not seem to populate the same name array variable outside the 'fetch' section

Comment: I'm not able of debugging your code since I'm not in control of neither the fetch call nor your environment. You need to set breakpoints at the critical lines of code. But in case you know any of the intermediate results e.g. fetched xml code we can work from there.

Comment: 1/2 ... maybe you provide again the exact specification of the data-structure which is going to get consumed by whatever google service/api. What you were asking for was ... `marqueurCanonTest4[0] = { latitudeCanon: "-34.94570", longitudeCanon: "138.58050", /* ... */ };`and `marqueurCanonTest4[1] = { latitudeCanon: "-36.14640", longitudeCanon: "146.91680", /* ... */ };` ...

Comment: 2/2 ... For the audience this looks like the first and the second data-item of an array that gets referred by the variable `marqueurCanonTest4`. Therefore all posted solutions did implement an approach that creates an array of data-items from a xml based data-structure.

Comment: If there is nothing else that can be done, the OP might consider accepting the answer which was most helpful for solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you need to create a markers array in JavaScript from the provided XML file.

You'll need to parse the XML content and extract the necessary data. You can achieve this using the browser's DOMParser to convert the XML string into a DOM object and then traverse the nodes to extract the marker information.

Here's an example of how you can do this:

```js
// Fetch the XML file
fetch('path/to/your/file.xml')
  .then(response => {
    // Check if the response is successful
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }
    // Parse the response as text
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(xmlString => {
    // Parse the XML string
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, 'text/xml');

    // Extract marker information
    const markers = Array.from(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('marker')).map(marker => ({
      lat: marker.getAttribute('lat'),
      lng: marker.getAttribute('lng'),
      name: marker.getAttribute('name'),
      category: marker.getAttribute('category'),
      nation: marker.getAttribute('nation'),
      typecanon: marker.getAttribute('typecanon'),
      lieu: marker.getAttribute('lieu'),
      pays: marker.getAttribute('pays'),
      url: marker.getAttribute('url'),
    }));

    // Output the markers array
    console.log(markers);

    // Use the 'markers' array in further processing here or within this scope
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('There was a problem fetching the file:', error);
  });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
  const mockedXmlResponse = {
    ok: true,
    text: () => new Promise(resolve => 
      resolve(
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
<markers> 
  <marker lat="50.84310" lng="4.39330" name="7.7cm Sockel Flak 16 RheinMetall" category="FlakKanonen" nation="Allemagne" typecanon="Artillerie de DCA" lieu="Bruxelles - MusÃ©e Royal de l'ArmÃ©e" pays="Belgique" url="../AfficheCanonGET.php?IdCanonAffiche=170" /> 
  <marker lat="43.13810" lng="-80.26170" name="15cm sFH 13 L/14" category="SchwerenKanonen" nation="Allemagne" typecanon="Artillerie lourde" lieu="Brantford (ON) - Monument" pays="Canada" url="../AfficheCanonGET.php?IdCanonAffiche=256" />  
  <marker lat="61.00500" lng="24.45780" name="10cm K 14" category="LeichtKanonen" nation="Allemagne" typecanon="Artillerie lÃ©gÃ¨re" lieu="Hameenlinna - Finnish Artillery Museum" pays="Finlande" url="../AfficheCanonGET.php?IdCanonAffiche=317" />  
  <marker lat="45.88740" lng="11.04740" name="7cm M 99 GebK" category="GebirgsKanonen" nation="Autriche-Hongrie" typecanon="Artillerie de montagne" lieu="Rovereto - Museo Storico Italiano della Guerra" pays="Italie" url="../AfficheCanonGET.php?IdCanonAffiche=733" /><marker lat="-35.21550" lng="149.14510" name="13cm K 09 L/35" category="SchwerenKanonen" nation="Allemagne" typecanon="Artillerie lourde" lieu=" Mitchell, ACT - AWM reserve" pays="Australie" url="../AfficheCanonGET.php?IdCanonAffiche=1519" /> 
</markers>`
      )
    ),
  };

  // mocking JavaScript's fetch function.
  function fetch(url) {
    console.log(`fetching ... $${ url }`);

    return new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(resolve, 1500, mockedXmlResponse)
    );
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the code i integrated Yesterday. Thé wanted table is correctly shown in thé console but i am stepping on a basic issue : although i declared before thé 'fetch' call  a var array with thé same name as thé array created in your code, it IS not populated by the fetch result. Should i add a 'return' ?

Comment: Can you show what you are doing? It is unclear, but do you want a global variable that should hold the same array of items currently printed on the console (inside a promise)?

Comment: Sure !  I am using you code the following way. My issue is that it seems the array created inside your 'fetch' does not populate the same name array variable declared outside and used to create the markers on the map.

Comment: Hi, I just realized how to integrate yout code and it works fine. Thank you for your efficient help !

Comment: Glad to help you!! Please mark this as an accepted answer for other's reference.

Answer (score 0):

Using Powershell

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$filename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($filename)

$markers = $doc.Descendants('markers')[0]

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($marker in $markers.Elements())
{
  $newRow = [pscustomobject]@{}
  foreach($attribute in $marker.Attributes())
  {
     $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $attribute.Name.LocalName -NotePropertyValue $attribute.Value
  }

  $table.Add($newRow) | Out-Null
}
$table | Format-List
```

Results

```
lat       : 50.84310
lng       : 4.39330
name      : 7.7cm Sockel Flak 16 RheinMetall
category  : FlakKanonen
nation    : Allemagne
typecanon : Artillerie de DCA
lieu      : Bruxelles - MusÃ©e Royal de l'ArmÃ©e
pays      : Belgique
url       : ../AfficheCanonGET.php?IdCanonAffiche=170

lat       : 43.13810
lng       : -80.26170
name      : 15cm sFH 13 L/14
category  : SchwerenKanonen
nation    : Allemagne
typecanon : Artillerie lourde
lieu      : Brantford (ON) - Monument
pays      : Canada
url       : ../AfficheCanonGET.php?IdCanonAffiche=256

lat       : 61.00500
lng       : 24.45780
name      : 10cm K 14
category  : LeichtKanonen
nation    : Allemagne
typecanon : Artillerie lÃ©gÃ¨re
lieu      : Hameenlinna - Finnish Artillery Museum
pays      : Finlande
url       : ../AfficheCanonGET.php?IdCanonAffiche=317

lat       : 45.88740
lng       : 11.04740
name      : 7cm M 99 GebK
category  : GebirgsKanonen
nation    : Autriche-Hongrie
typecanon : Artillerie de montagne
lieu      : Rovereto - Museo Storico Italiano della Guerra
pays      : Italie
url       : ../AfficheCanonGET.php?IdCanonAffiche=733

lat       : -35.21550
lng       : 149.14510
name      : 13cm K 09 L/35
category  : SchwerenKanonen
nation    : Allemagne
typecanon : Artillerie lourde
lieu      :  Mitchell, ACT - AWM reserve
pays      : Australie
url       : ../AfficheCanonGET.php?IdCanonAffiche=1519
```

Comment: Thanks you ! I had no Idea this could bé donne si simple

Answer (score 0):

An approach needs to be based on ...

- [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#syntax)ing the XML-file by making use of the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)
- [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and [parsing an (XML) document from the fetched XML-text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString#examples)
- retrieving the data from the parsed XML-DOM via e.g.

  - the query selector API and here [`document.querySelectorAll('marker')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
  - collecting an array of to be newly created data-items by iterating the queried list of element-nodes via e.g. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

In addition one could choose to handle the asynchronous API calls by an [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) main function which makes use of the [await operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) in order to await the results of such deferred operations.

The beneath provided example code does mock both the `fetch` method and the method's api response in order to provide a working example of the full data-related round trip.

Choosing `reduce` for creating and aggregating an new data-item from each currently `map`ped marker-element is due to gaining flexibility in regards of changes to the XML markup.

While mapping a marker-element one would retrieve a list of all of its attribute-names via [`getAttributeNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttributeNames). Parsing the attribute node-list into an array via [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) enables the iteration of all attribute-names via [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). One then can aggregate an [initially passed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#how_reduce_works_with_an_initial_value) empty object / `{}`.

With every iteration step one has access to the currently processed attribute-name. Having provided an object as lookup-table allows for a fast lookup of the XML attribute-name's related property-name of the to be aggregated data-item. Thus, with each iteration step one is able of creating a new key-value pair from the correctly looked up key-name.

The solution in its entirety then looks like follows ...

```js
const markerAttrToKeyLookup = {
  lat: 'latitudeCanon',
  lng: 'longitudeCanon',
  name: 'nomCanon',
  category: 'categorieCanon',
  nation: 'nationCanon',
  typecanon: 'typeCanon',
  lieu: 'lieuCanon',
  pays: 'paysCanon',
  url: 'url',
}

function createMarkerListFromXmlDocument(xmlDocument) {
  return [
    ...xmlDocument.querySelectorAll('marker')
  ]
  .map(markerElement => {

    return [...markerElement.getAttributeNames()]
      .reduce((markerItem, attrName) => {

        const key = markerAttrToKeyLookup[attrName];
        
        markerItem[key] = markerElement.getAttribute(attrName);

        return markerItem;

      }, {})
  });
}

async function main() {

  const response = await fetch('path/to/file.xml');
  const xmlText = await response.text();

  console.log({ xmlText });

  const xmlDocument = (new DOMParser)
    .parseFromString(xmlText, 'text/xml');

  // console.log({ xmlDocument });

  const markerList =
    createMarkerListFromXmlDocument(xmlDocument);

  console.log({ markerList });
}
main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
  const mockedXmlResponse = {
    ok: true,
    text: () => new Promise(resolve => 
      resolve(
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
<markers> 
  <marker lat="50.84310" lng="4.39330" name="7.7cm Sockel Flak 16 RheinMetall" category="FlakKanonen" nation="Allemagne" typecanon="Artillerie de DCA" lieu="Bruxelles - MusÃ©e Royal de l'ArmÃ©e" pays="Belgique" url="../AfficheCanonGET.php?IdCanonAffiche=170" /> 
  <marker lat="43.13810" lng="-80.26170" name="15cm sFH 13 L/14" category="SchwerenKanonen" nation="Allemagne" typecanon="Artillerie lourde" lieu="Brantford (ON) - Monument" pays="Canada" url="../AfficheCanonGET.php?IdCanonAffiche=256" />  
  <marker lat="61.00500" lng="24.45780" name="10cm K 14" category="LeichtKanonen" nation="Allemagne" typecanon="Artillerie lÃ©gÃ¨re" lieu="Hameenlinna - Finnish Artillery Museum" pays="Finlande" url="../AfficheCanonGET.php?IdCanonAffiche=317" />  
  <marker lat="45.88740" lng="11.04740" name="7cm M 99 GebK" category="GebirgsKanonen" nation="Autriche-Hongrie" typecanon="Artillerie de montagne" lieu="Rovereto - Museo Storico Italiano della Guerra" pays="Italie" url="../AfficheCanonGET.php?IdCanonAffiche=733" /><marker lat="-35.21550" lng="149.14510" name="13cm K 09 L/35" category="SchwerenKanonen" nation="Allemagne" typecanon="Artillerie lourde" lieu=" Mitchell, ACT - AWM reserve" pays="Australie" url="../AfficheCanonGET.php?IdCanonAffiche=1519" /> 
</markers>`
      )
    ),
  };

  // mocking JavaScript's fetch function.
  function fetch(url) {
    console.log(`fetching ... $${ url }`);

    return new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(resolve, 1500, mockedXmlResponse)
    );
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks you ! I will test the code in my script in the next days

Comment: @bernard1418 ... And, what is/was the outcome of your testing?

Comment: Peter, sorry for the delay answering. I have been very busy at work and could only test the solution today... I gate the correct import shown in the console.log, but I can't use the results on the map as I do not know how th 'export' the 'markerList' array in my main script in which I embedded your functon. Probably an easy fix, but I am sorry I am such a beginner to request help for this? Bernard